# Test class with implicit class using ScalaMock

Tags: scala, unit-testing, apache-spark, mocking, scalamock

Suppose I have a trait with read operations wrapped inside a Try block:

```scala
import scala.util.Try

trait ReadingProvider[T] {
  def readTable(tableName: String):Try[T]
}
```

Also a class which provides methods for reading with spark and an implicit class for methods to recover from failure

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType
import scala.util.{Try, Success, Failure}

class SparkReadingProvider(spark: SparkSession) extends ReadingProvider[DataFrame] {
  override readTable: Try[DataFrame] = Try(spark.read.table(tableName))

  def createEmptyDF(schema: StructType): DataFrame =spark.createDataFrame(spark.sparkContext.emptyRDD[Row], schema)

}

  implicit class ReadingHandler(tryDF: Try[DataFrame]) {

    def recoverWithEmptyDF(schema: StructType): DataFrame = tryDF match {
        case Failure(ex) => //Log something
          createEmptyDF(schema)
        case Success(df) => //Log something
          df
      }
  }
}
```

Now I have an object which contains the reading and some transformation:

```scala
object MyObject {

  def readSomeTable(tableName): SparkReadingProvider => DataFrame = provider => {
    import provider.ReadingHandler
    provider.readTable(tableName).recoverWithEmptyDF
    }

  def transform: DataFrame => DataFrame = ???

  def mainMethod(tableName)(implicit val provider: SparkReadingProvider): DataFrame =
    readSomeTable(tableName) andThen transform apply provider

}
```

I want to unit test the methods inside `MyObject`. I don't want to work with real files or tables, thus my goal is to use mocking.

In my test I was trying to mock the SparkReadingProvider:

```scala
describe("reading") {
  it("should return empty dataframe when reading failed") {
    val provider: SparkReadingProvider = mock[SparkReadingProvider]
    val tableName: String = "no_table"
    provider.readTable _ expects tableName returning Failure(new Exception("Table does not exist"))
    MyObject.readSomeTable(tableName) shouldBe empty
    }
}
```

However it fails with the error:

> Unexpected call: < mock-1> SparkReadingProvider.ReaderHandler(Failure(java.lang.Exception: table does not exist))
>
> Expected:
>    inAnyOrder {
>    < mock-1> SparkReadingProvider.readTable(no_table) once (called once)
>    }
>
> Actual:
>    < mock-1> SparkReadingProvider.readTable(no_table)
>    < mock-1> SparkReadingProvider.ReaderHandler(Failure(java.lang.Exception: table does not exist))

My questions are:

- Is it possible to achieve what I want in the current setup?
- If not, how should I refactor my code
- If I test in a different class the methods available in the implicit class, does it make sense to test the `readSomeTable` and the `mainMethod` inside `MyObject`?

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that extension methods are basically a syntactic sugar.

I will be explaining using an example.

```
trait Foo
implicit class FooImplicit(foo: Foo) {
  def bar: String = "bar
}

foo.bar
```

is translated to

```
new FooImplicit(foo).bar
```

So mocking:

```
Mockito.when(foo.bar).thenReturn("bad")
```

becomes:

```
Mockito.when(new FooImplicit(foo).bar).thenReturn("bad")
```

Note how `foo.bar` is treated and that's the issue.

> Is it possible to achieve what I want in the current setup?

No, I don't think it is possible in the current setup.

> If not, how should I refactor my code

The only way to achieve that is to use implicit conversions rather than implicit classes.

I will be showing an example how this could be achieved:

```
trait Foo {
  def bar: String
}

object ImplicitFoo {
  object implicits {
    implicit fooToFooImplicit(foo: Foo): FooOps = new FooImplicit(foo)
    class FooImplicit(foo: Foo) {
      def bar: String = "bar"
    }
  }
}
```

and your test

```
import org.scalatest.WordSpec
import org.mockito.MockitoSugar

  class MySpec extends WordSpec with MockitoSugar {
    "My mock" should {
      "handle methods from implicit classes" in {
        val fooOps = mock[FooImplicit]
        implicit fooToOps(foo: Foo): FooImplicit = fooOps
        val foo = mock[Foo]
        when(foo.bar) thenReturn "bad" // works
      }
    }
  }
```

In your production you need to get an implicit parameter of the shape `Foo => FooImplicit` so when you call that method from the test the actual implicit mock is provided...

> If I test in a different class the methods available in the implicit
>   class, does it make sense to test the readSomeTable and the mainMethod
>   inside MyObject?

I do not think that you require to test the readSomeTable and the mainMethod inside MyObject.But other way round is true.

Let me know if it helps!!